# Fill PDF from mssql database using MVC

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, pdf, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I want to fetch the data from my database to populate some fields in the PDF, I have my sample code of my MVC, my need some help with SP because I am not really familiar with SQL, any kind of help would be appreciated.

**Controller**

```
function downloadform()
        {   

                $data['info']= $this->uri->segment(3);
                $this->load->model('navi_model');
                $query =  $this->navi_model->gen048_welletter($data);
                $data['viewlist'] = $query;
            //  $hello = $this->load->view('view', $data);
                $this->load->library('mpdf');       



                $hello ='
                <img src="'.base_url().'images/ubplogo.png"></img>
                <br/><br/>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                <td width="18%"><strong>Request No. :</strong></td> <td> <span class="space">'.$data['viewlist'][0]->accnum .'</span></td>
                <td width="15%">  <strong>Control Code:</strong></td> <td style="color: blue;">'.$data['viewlist'][0]->accname . '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Date Created:</strong></td><td>'. $data['viewlist'][0]->Date_Created .'</td>
                    <td><strong>Last Edited:</strong></td><td>' . $data['viewlist'][0]->Date_Edited .'</td>
                </tr>';
```

**Model**

```
function gen048_welletter($data)
{

$qString = '[gen048_welcomeletter] '; //STORED PROCEDURE
    $qString .= "'" 
             . $data['info'] . "','";

        //echo $qString;

        $this->db->query('set ansi_padding on
                        set ARITHABORT on
                        set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on
                        set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
                        set ANSI_NULLS on
                        set ANSI_WARNINGS on
                        set numeric_roundabort off');

        $query = $this->db->query($qString);

    //return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : NULL;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code?

Comment: My pdf letter template is displaying but I need to fetch data from my database to address every letter to the names in my database. I just put SELECT * FROM (tablename) on my stored procedure but its not working.